# Javascript Sinus not correct

Tags: javascript, math

I am working with a friend on a little port from the bukkit plugin WorldEdit to the minecraft pocket edition. The scripts are in JavaScript (so forget jQuery).

I was testing my theoretical calculations to check if I can calculate the height of c (hc) if I know the length of a and the beta angle.

[image: Triangle]

Example data:
a: 20 cm
beta: 40°

Formula to calculate hc:

```
sin(40)*20
```

Result:

```
12.85575219374
```

I tested the formula at Chrome and IE and I got

```
14.902263209586957
```

Am I doing something wrong or has my calculator/pc problems?

Greetings

miny

Comment: Be aware that the angle is expected in radians, not degrees.

Comment: The argument must be in radians, not degrees

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways of representing angles (degrees or radians). In your calculation you are using degrees, but the function `sin` expects radians. So you need to convert degrees to radians.

```
function degToRad(deg) {
   return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

Comment: Thx, I am really new at tringonomy, I had that never in the school. :S